# How to set an fillArea offset in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, data-visualization, area

I try to set an reference value for a area-plot in higcharts. this should be similar to [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-negative/gray) but with 100 as baseline. Because its hard to describe i attach a picture. I'm really lost on this topic, thanks for any help/hint in advance.

[image: image to describe the problem]

Comment: could you share your code? you can set yAxis min/max depending on the values.

Comment: yAxis:{
        min:80,
            max:170
        }, See this http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/th3s5aw9/

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi, I think what MemLeak is saying is that he wants Joe's area plot to start rising at 100, whereas the one you linked to it starts at 0 and cover's Jane's area plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`threshold` was what im looking for. add it to the series, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3gco1j3/2/)

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [105, 103, 104, 107, 102],
    threshold : 100
} ....
```

Comment: Oh, go figure! Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can set the baseline to actually be anything other than 0, but what you can do is modify the axis such that it displays the actual value we're graphing offset by 100. Then for your data, you can offset it by the same amount in the opposite direction.

```
yAxis: {           
    labels: {
         formatter: function () {
             return [this.value + 100];
         }
    }
},
series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [105, 103, 104, 107, 102].offset(-100)
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [102, 98, 97, 102, 101].offset(-100)
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [103, 104, 104, 98, 105].offset(-100)
    }
]
```

Where

```
Array.prototype.offset = function (ofs) {
    var a = [];
    this.forEach(function (d) {
        a.push(d + ofs);
    });
    return a;
};
```

Doing that I created the graph you were hoping for:

[image]

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gsabnk58/1/)